# pandas: count values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently doing a project that i need to count the popularity of each genre per year. The dataset gives me movies but each movie can have multiple Genres as shown in the sample df below (also with messy format genres separated by "|")

```
    release_year                                     genres
0          2015  Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
1          2015  Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
2          2015         Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
3          2015   Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy
4          2015                      Action|Crime|Thriller
```

MY first step was to split each genre into different columns in order to have clean data to work with by using str.split

```
df[['Genre_1','Genre_2','Genre_3','Genre_4','Genre_5']] = df['genres'].str.split("|",expand=True)

    release_year   Genre_1          Genre_2          Genre_3   Genre_4  Genre_5
0          2015     Action        Adventure  Science Fiction  Thriller    None
1          2015     Action        Adventure  Science Fiction  Thriller    None
2          2015  Adventure  Science Fiction         Thriller      None    None
3          2015     Action        Adventure  Science Fiction   Fantasy    None
4          2015     Action            Crime         Thriller      None    None
```

How can i use a groupby statement to count the popularity of each genre per year since each movies has multiple ones? It looks like that i want to collapse all the columns that i expanded but keeping the year key for each one, ideally leading to something like this:

```
    release_year   All genres
0          2015     Action 
1          2015     Action 
2          2015  Adventure
3          2015     Action
4          2015     Action
```

I would really appreciate any help on this one.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does your desired output have duplicate rows with same year **and** same genre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following would give you the required output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [2015, 'Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller'],
        [2015, 'Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller'],
        [2015, ' Action|Crime|Thriller']
    ],
    columns=['release_year', 'genres']

)
df2 = df['genres'].str.split('|').apply(pd.Series)
df2.index = df.set_index(['release_year']).index
df2.stack().reset_index(['release_year']).rename(columns={0: 'All Genres'})
```

Output:

```
   release_year       All Genres
0          2015           Action
1          2015        Adventure
2          2015  Science Fiction
3          2015         Thriller
0          2015           Action
1          2015        Adventure
2          2015  Science Fiction
3          2015         Thriller
0          2015           Action
1          2015            Crime
2          2015         Thriller
```

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding..